# how to select value wierd soap - xml

Tags: xslt, select, soap

i'm new to xsl and i want to know how i can select value of the field r1

this is my xml (not a 100% soap)

---

```
<Result>
<send>
    <x>1</x>
</send>
<received>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns1:Consult xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.org/New/">
        <message>
            <r1>2</r1>
        </message>
        </ns1:Consult>
    </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
</received>
</Result>
```

---

and i tried this

```
<xsl:value-of select="/Result/received/soap:Envelope/soap:Body[1]/*[namespace-uri()='http://www.example.org/New/' and local-name()='Consult'][1]/message/r1"/>
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register the SOAP namespace:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of
            select="/Result/received/soap:Envelope/soap:Body[1]/*[
                        namespace-uri()='http://www.example.org/New/' 
                        and local-name()='Consult'][1]/message/r1" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Better yet, register them both:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.org/New/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of
            select="/Result/received/soap:Envelope/
                        soap:Body[1]/ns1:Consult[1]/message/r1" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```